# HTML5 Screensaver for OSX, Windows, Linux; Is it possible?

Tags: html, cross-platform, screensaver

I'm not sure if I'm putting this on the correct forum but still would like to ask and wondering. Is it possible to cook up a screensaver that would run on OSX, Windows and Linux (Ubuntu perhaps)?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NodeWebkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), I am sure you can find a way to pack it as screensaver for all platforms.
[Windows One](https://github.com/sinky/html5-screensaver-node-webkit)